# Ubuntu drivers for TP-Link AXE5400 Archer TXE75E

Tags: drivers, wireless, ubuntu-drivers, pcie, tp-link

I have recently got a [TP-Link AXE5400 Archer TXE75E WiFi PCIE card](https://www.tp-link.com/de/home-networking/adapter/archer-txe75e/).
I have a Windows 10, Ubuntu 20.04 Dual Boot System.
The cards comes with drivers for Windows which work well.
On Ubuntu there are no official drivers, only the Bluetooth antenna is recognized.
The WiFi is not detected (No WiFI adapter found).
Are there any Ubuntu drivers available online that would be compatible with this card?

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
```

outputs:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0024]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

The command

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

outputs:

```
[    3.946374] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.958162] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    3.958181] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[    3.958548] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.419879] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    4.583922] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x324cd670
[    4.689765] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[    4.689770] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    4.689774] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 1
[    4.897763] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware didn't ACK the reset - continue anyway
[    4.909541] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

To write this post the computer is connected to my Smartphone WiFi via USB-Hotspot.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: All is looking good. What does `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` show? And what is the kernel version?

Comment: Also you need to disable Fast Startup in Windows to be able using this device in dual boot.

Comment: Fast Startup is disabled, since I read it can cause problems in dual boot.

Comment: So what is the kernel version?

Comment: uname -r -> 5.11.0-27-generic

Comment: This kernel is EoL. Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and reboot.

Comment: Upgrading to 5.15.0-47-generic and Ubuntu 22.04 solved the issue. The WiFi adapter is now found. Thank you!